# Get only numbers from array of strings if string matches

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array.

```
["mango-1", "mango-3", "cilantro-3"]
```

I need a new array that gets **just the numbers** from each **mango-** item. So

```
["1", "3"]
```

I've tried so many things I can't keep track. Any help?

Comment: You initially have an array of three elements, but you ask that the return should have the unique values. I mean it should be [1,3,3] but you want [1,3]. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes hi, you could use a regular expression replacement. Since your tag is jQuery, that can be done with [jQuery `map`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/):

```js
var myArray = ['mango-1', 'mango-3', 'cilantro-3'];

var mangos = $.map(myArray, function(val) {
    match = val.match(/^mango-([0-9]+)$/);
    return match && match[1];
});

console.log(mangos);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The result is:

```
["1", "3"]
```

Or pure javascript with [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: I never realized that `jQuery.map()` automatically filters out `null` return values.

Comment: This did exactly what I needed! Thank you @IronMan!

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter()` to get just the elements that begin with `mango-`, them map `replace()` to remove the `mango-` prefixes.

```js
let array =  ["mango-1", "mango-3", "cilantro-3"];
let result = array.filter(s => s.startsWith("mango-")).map(s => s.replace("mango-", ""));
console.log(result);
```

or use `reduce()` to do both the test and replacement in a single callback function.

```js
let array = ["mango-1", "mango-3", "cilantro-3"];
let result = array.reduce((a, s) => {
  if (s.startsWith("mango-")) {
    a.push(s.replace("mango-", ""));
  }
  return a;
}, []);
console.log(result);
```